# bitbucket hg clone 404 error, failed at 'updating to branch default'

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

When cloning a repo from bitbucket I came across a weird error.
Hg would stuck at `updating to branch default` step for a long long time and then fail.

see shell screen copy below:

```
~/projects » hg clone ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/akhayyat/mezzanine-pagedown                                                                              
destination directory: mezzanine-pagedown
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 55 changesets with 101 changes to 39 files
updating to branch default
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
------------------------------------------------------------
~/projects » cd mezzanine-pagedown                                                                                                                    
------------------------------------------------------------
~/projects/mezzanine-pagedown » hg status                                                                                                            
? .hgignore
? .hgsub
? .hgsubstate
? .hgtags
? LICENSE
? MANIFEST.in
? README.md
? mezzanine_pagedown/__init__.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/defaults.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/fields.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/filters.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/management/__init__.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/management/commands/__init__.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/management/commands/pygments_styles.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/models.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/static/mezzanine_pagedown/css/pagedown.css
? mezzanine_pagedown/static/mezzanine_pagedown/js/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js
? mezzanine_pagedown/static/mezzanine_pagedown/js/jquery.cookie.js
? mezzanine_pagedown/templates/mezzanine_pagedown/editor.html
? mezzanine_pagedown/urls.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/views.py
? mezzanine_pagedown/widgets.py
? setup.py
------------------------------------------------------------
~/projects/mezzanine-pagedown » hg update                                                                                                              
abort: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
--------------------------------
```

sometimes it's

```
updating to branch default
abort: error: Network is unreachable
remote: Connection to bitbucket.org closed by remote host.
```

I have tried it on my laptop, pc and digitalocean vps, all failed.

Can you try cloning this repo and see if you can succeseed?

What might have gone wrong, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It is a migration issue.
project owner gave the answer:

> This is happening because the original PageDown javascript project on
>   Google Code, which is a subrepository of this repository, is now gone:
>   https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagedown/.